# Path connectedness implies continuity.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was thinking about the continuity discussion that took place in the spanish comunity and I thought if we have:

$$f: A \longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad A \subset \mathbb{R}.$$

Such that $Graph(f)$ is connected but it is not path connected so $f$ is not continuos in his domain, For example:
$$
h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x \in(0, 1) \\
0 & x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

$Graph(h)$ is connected because it can’t be expressed as the disjoint union of two non empty open sets. But it is not path connected because it includes the point $(0,0)$ but there is no way to link the function to the origin so as to make a path.

In conclusion if $graph(f)$ is connected but it is not path connected so it is not continuos and if it is path connected it is continuos?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this page related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954664/continuous-if-and-only-if-graph-of-every-path-connected-subspace-is-path-connect

Comment: This is covered by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2928893. In this question one considers an arbitrary $A \subset \mathbb R$. It greatly simplifies for intervals.

Comment: Wow I  did not found that question thank both of you